# How to sign an xml with sha1-rsa base64 in java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, encryption

I have a problem, a WS requires me to sign what I send in sha1-rsa base64, I made a script who encodes the string with the xml, but It seems to need another type of encoding, I heard something about XML Signature, that is diferent to normal signature.
I have a private and a public key, a xml in a string, the rest of the xml where I need to put the encoded xml, and the url to send it.
Sorry if my english bad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the Java [XML digital signature library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/package-summary.html). A description by Sean can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).

You may need an X509 certificate instead of just a public key. This certificate needs to be trusted somehow at the side of the receiver. Without trust, a digital signature is useless.

---

The encoding is part of the library, you don't need to do that yourself.

The sending of the signed data is *not* part of the signature generation. I'll leave the sending of data to an URL for another question though.